# Screenshot with custom header

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using phantomJS to take a screenshot of the page. There are options of passing custom header parameter using `page.paperSize` parameter.

My code is below but no header is getting printed on the resulting image. Neither I am getting any error. Any hint in this regard is highly appreciated.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 600, 
  height: 500
};

page.open('https://twitter.com/MaraWilson/status/960451771444310016', function() {
  page.paperSize = {
    width: '8.5in',
    height: '11in',
    header: {
      height: "1cm",
      contents: phantom.callback(function() {
        return "<h1>Header <span style='float:right'>Test</span></h1>";
      })
    },
  };    

  page.render('test.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

The resultant image that I get is as follows **No Headers at all**:

[image]

**Update:**
After getting the suggestions from @Vaviloff and reading the docs carefully, it became clear that page.paperSize is used only for PDF documents. But my question is specific to PNG.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/paper-size.html

> **paperSize {object}**
>   This property defines the size of the web page when rendered as a PDF.

So you should render the page into a PDF, not an image.

Another idea: try making header a bit higher — when testing your code I had to make the header 3cm high to actually see the test text.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Got it once I read the docs carefully. I want the rendering to be in PNG only. I was trying it by injecting a custom javascript and changing the look of the page. Hoping to get it solved soon.

Comment: Well, it this was the right answer, you might mark is as such :)

Comment: No it is not the right answer. I was talking about the getting a custom header in images. What I got after reading the docs is that paperSize can only be used with PDF rendering. But I want to render in PNG. So this is not suitable.

Comment: `no header is getting printed on the resulting image. Neither I am getting any error. Any hint in this regard is highly appreciated` I gave you the exact reason as to why there's no header, so if this is not "not suitable", I guess you need to learn to define your questions better :)

Comment: Sorry for the misinterpretation. But I have explicitly mentioned `resultant image` that I get is as follows No Headers at all. Your solutions adds clarity that I was using it wrong but unfortunately doesn't solves it. Just for clarification: The hint that I am asking is with regard to the image. I am adding the clarity provided by you in the question itself.  Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, to do what you want you'll have to modify Twiiter's DOM and insert a custom header yourself, doing so in `page.evaluate`. Do you know how to do that (in theory, at least)?

Comment: I have implemented it. Thanks for the suggestions. Will be posting the solution soon